# Change user on Facebook login based on OAuth2

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, google-signin

So, I prepared OAuth2 login based on Facebook and Google. That's work perfectly, but...

**Scenario #1:**
When a user is logged in Facebook (in browser session) and open my website, next click on button "Login with Facebook", when everything will be fine, then has access. And It's okay!

**Scenario #2:**
When a user is logged in Facebook (in browser session) and open my website, next click on button "Login with Facebook", but He would like to change the Facebook account to other, but there is no something like screen (prompt) to choose a user. And this is a problem...

Google has something like `prompt=select_account` variable in OAuth2 URL.
There is something similar in Facebook?

P.S. I'm not interested in existing libraries or APIs.

Comment: No there isn’t, and since Facebook does not want you to have more than one personal account to begin with, that is not a use case they are very eager to support to in the first place. You can log a user out to varying degrees with an API call, but getting that to work correctly and the way you want it to can be a bit of a hassle.